# How to copy Posable Models With textures

Tags: texturing

How can i copy a posable model with Actual image textures (A Robot, Clothed human,
Wizard, The character in the picture below, ECT.) from a running instance of blender, Over to another instance with CTRL C CRTL P?. (An enviroment, Room, ShowStage, ECT.)[image]

Comment: You dont need to use copy/paste. With the Blender you want the model in. Go to File> Append and choose the scene of the file you want.

Comment: @TrovianJack so all you want to do is "copy" the object, rig and textures to another blend file?

Comment: No i want to Copy them over to another running instance of Blender. Y'know Copy Paste?

Comment: Also i have no experience with appending. Im saying i have no clue what to append to get it all in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the .blend file, then in the new instance of Blender go to `File -> Append` and select the object.

[image]
[image]

Comment: When i select "Object" it goes into the folder and i don't know what to select.

Comment: You would want to select the character that you are trying to copy, that would be whatever you named it.

Comment: Ok Thanks i got it! Thank you Sooooo Much!

Comment: Glad to help :)